# Using grep to find a file that contains a string

Tags: unix

My .htaccess file in my htdocs folder does not work. I tried to redirect to Google when accessing a filename. I want to find out where the settings for my httpd.conf are, so I can enable mod_rewrite. I did the following UNIX command to find out if a httpd.conf file existed on my hard drive:

```
find * -name "httpd.conf"
```

The file does not exist. I am thinking that maybe there is another file that controls mod_rewrite. I want to see if "AllowOverride" exists in any directory. I entered the following UNIX command:

```
grep -r "AllowOverride" *
```

But it's hard to read because it prints out so many folders. The message that accompanies the folders are "Permission denied" or "No such file or directory". How do I only get the file paths of files that contain AllowOverride?

Comment: Try suppressing stderr with `2> /dev/null`

Comment: You're using `find` incorrectly. Don't use `*` for your path; use `.` or `/` or something else instead. One path only...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many Unix and similar systems provide a `locate(1)` command that uses a database to speed finding individual files. Try this:

```
locate httpd.conf
```

Note, of course, that Apache configurations are stored in files of all sorts of names; I've seen `apache.conf`, `httpd.conf`, `httpd2.conf`, and then there's the giant pile of `/etc/apache2/conf.d/` -- entire directory structures set aside for configuring Apache. Your distribution may vary.

Perhaps [`apachectl configtest`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html) will show the paths? (currently not installed on my machine, so I can't easily test.)

Answer (score 4):

Try this command:

```
 find / -name "httpd.conf" 2>1 | grep -v "Permission denied"
```

the `2>1` funnels `stderr` to `stdout` so that both can be piped into the [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) utility. `grep` in turn will print anyline that doesn't have the string "Permission denied" in it (the `-v` negates/inverts the matching of the search string)

If you don't redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, the output of `stderr` to the console would bypass the rest of the command line.

You could *extend* the above command line by *appending* this:

```
| grep -v "No such file or directory"
```

if that string was coming up and you wanted to suppress it too.

This tells you [all about io redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html). And here's a nice [quick summary](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/).

Comment: Another nice option is to just throw away all the errors: `find / -name httpd.conf 2> /dev/null`.

Comment: @sarnold .. that's true, I like to have them though, just in case I want to filter on them (and I'm lazy, so I'll just use the same initial command line). `locate` is a good solution as long as `updatedb` runs regularly. I once worked at a place that didn't have a cron job and I didn't have sudo to run it :-(

Comment: Eeep, no `updatedb` database, that'd be so tiring... hooray for `locate`. :)

Comment: @sarnold Agreed. For a long time, before I figured out `find` I was depending on `locate` only (and usually query it first)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
  find / -type f -exec grep -n "AllowOverride" {} \; -print 2>/dev/null
```

To scan files containing the "AllowOverride" string from the root, if you want to run the search in a particular directory, use the following instead:

```
  find /path/to/directory -type f -exec grep -n "AllowOverride" {} \; -print 2>/dev/null
```

The output should only print the files containing the specified string along with the number of the matching line